# CS GO running but not showing

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, steam, amd-graphics

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 Gnome. I installed Steam and then installed Counter Strike Global Offensive(CS GO). When I launch CS GO, Steam says it is running while CS GO doesn't show up. When I again launch CS GO, a window appears saying that game is already running please close it. 
My video card is **R9 270**. I'm using open-source driver, not sure whether it is **radeon** or **amdgpu**. I'm pasting below video card spec of my pc:

```
~$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7d00000-f7d3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d40000-f7d5ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

When we go the settings and click details icon, then the following info appears about my graphics:

```
Gallium 0.4 on AMD PITCAIRN (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
```

What is the problem that's causing CS GO not to show up? Please help me, I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: go to settings->softwares&update-> additional drivers and check your graphics drivers

Comment: It says proprietary intel driver in use. However, I want to make my game show up.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully I got the issue resolved. What I did was that I found this [post](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4451) while searching and used the command written in fourth comment by **teresko**.

The command is:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so' steam
```

Moreover, I found that Gnome actually causes error with CSGO. When I use the above command, CSGO ran, but Gnome showed an error that OpenGl is not working, I closed the error window and CSGO kept on running like butter without any issue.

I hope this will help others.